# Как из request вытащить параметр в blade, когда там массив, laravel?

Tags: laravel, requests

Всем привет!
Подскажите пжл, как с request вытащить request[1]
Всем заранее благодарен!

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51 ▼
    #parameters: array:5 [▼
      "price" => array:2 [▼
        1 => "111"
        2 => "222"
      ]
```

пробовал так, но увы((

```
request()->$price[1]
request('price[1]')
request("$price[1]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request('price.1')
```

все нашел, всем спасибо)